# Bad Company 2 freezes on Bootcamp

Tags: battlefield-bad-company-2, technical-issues, boot-camp

I'm trying to play Bad Company 2 on bootcamp (iMac "late 2009", windows XP single user "student whatever edition"), but the multiplayer apparently always freezes after less than 1 minute of play. I've tried playing on a server without punkbuster, but it freezes anyway.

The single player works fine instead, so I guess it's not an engine problem (unless the multiplayer is for some reason much heavier).

It's not an account problem either, because with the same account I play without problems from other PCs.

Does somebody have any idea what could be causing this, and how to fix that?

Comment: I'll vote for closing, since the question seems to have become an unwanted child (among many others).

Comment: @Bora: actually, I have not solved the problem yet.

Comment: Good to hear from you, well, not so good that the problem still persists. Is there any update on the issue, things that didn't work, for example? How can we help further?

Comment: The game supports push-to-talk microphone. Try disabling the microphone (via hardware, not via game), Unplug any and all joysticks. If you have steam, disable the game overlay (chat/friends/browser). In fact, ANYTHING which might pop up a message (IM, email application, etc.). There is a way to change the directx version via INI file in your user profile AFAIK

Comment: @horatio: nice ideas, I'll try them. Still, bear in mind that the single player worked, while the problems arised only on multiplayer, so I'm not sure how these things (beside the microphone) could do the trick.

Comment: I don't think think this game has a separate executable for MP (some games like Modern Warfare 2 & Crysis do), but it *might* still use a different code path. Shots in the dark, but that's the nature of the beast.

Comment: also: it locks up while in a match and not during server browser refresh or in the menus, correct?

Comment: @horatio: correct, but I didn't try to stay in the menus for too long.

Comment: On this page ( http://forum.ea.com/eaforum/posts/list/195/431165.page ) there are some instructions for diabling Punkbuster, removing some files, and reinstalling & updating punkbuster using evenbalance's updater ( http://www.evenbalance.com/index.php?page=pbsetup.php )

Comment: Yes but, again, keep in mind that I tried playing in non-punkbuster servers, and it froze anyway.

Comment: First of all Bootcamp doesn't have anything to do with it. What you have is XP running on fairly standard x86 laptop. Second -- XP is really, really old. It's no longer supported, it's 11 years and 3 generations an behind current Windows.

Comment: No one had a clue, and meanwhile that game is dead. Can be closed now.

Answer (score 1):

If you run any sensor programs ,Realtemp ,Trixx, Afterburner ,hardware monitor or any equipment that needs to address the memory range where punkbuster resides it will freeze.

Mine was a small software widget that came with my logitech g13 for monitoring CPU and Ram usage that auto ran in the background.

If you can play freeze free on non punkbuster servers , then you know for sure it is the punkbuster causing a conflict.

Answer (score 0):

It could be worth manually updating your punkbuster on the bootcamp partition as that can cause a lot of problems with most of the Battlefield games (BF2, BF2142 and BF:BC2 in my experience).

What do you mean when you say freezes? can you give any more details?

Comment: I'll try. With "freezes" I mean it completely locks up the computer and I have to hard-reboot, the image stays still and the audio I don't remember at the moment.

Comment: Have you tried the typical 'uninstall -> reinstall' process just to eliminate the possibly of a dodgy installation.

Comment: Of course not, it didn't even occur to me to do that; chances are that would be a huge waste of time.

Comment: I've known much crazier things to happen, all its takes is for one file to get corrupted and knob everything up (radial file in BF2142 for example). And this guy is running bootcamp so it kinda is windows :P

Comment: it is windows: windows OS, intel core2 hardware, realtek HD audio. etc etc.

Comment: I would tend to say Punkbuster, too.